# Некорректно переведён статус правки

Tags: дефект, локализация, предлагаемые-правки

В предложенных правках вместо "принята" и "отклонена" написано "принять" и "отклонить".

[image: скриншот]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибки локализации тут нет. Здесь такой дизайн. Пример с MSE:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Поэтому исправлять ситуацию надо начинать с MSE. Писать там FR, BR или искать существующие.